# Unable to upload file received in POST request to another API in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm uploading a PDF file using AngularJS to a upload.php on my server. The upload.php further uploads the `$_FILES` receive in POST request to another server through the API given using curl.

The `$_FILES` object contains the PDF file.

This is part of the upload.php which does the work:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $curl = curl_init();
    $payload = json_encode(array(
                'file' => "@$filedata", "filename" => $filename));
    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.mydmian.in/fileupload',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload
        )
    );
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

How can I convert $_FILES into a file object so that I can attach it in curl payload?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the contents of the uploaded file and store them in `$filedata` and then attach those to your `$payload`.

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$curl = curl_init();
$payload = json_encode(array(
            'file' => $filedata, "filename" => $filename));
curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.mydmian.in/fileupload',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload
    )
);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```